# Unable to edit ints

Tags: php, mysql, int

I'm building an admin panel in PHP. I'm new to PHP and I can't get my edit page to work as I need it to. I can edit the name, but 2 values which represent "Active User" and "Access Level" are set to 0 and I can't change it from 0 on my edit page, only from PhpmyAdmin..

```
<?php
// Inserir o registo na BD
include_once ('config1.php');

// Estabelecer a ligação à BD
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123456', 'admin1');

//Verificar se a ligação foi estabelecida com sucesso
if (mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    echo "</h2>Erro no acesso a BD</h2>" . mysqli_connect_error(); 

    exit();
    }
    // Validar se os campos do formulário foram preenchidos pelo utilizador
    // Verificar se "username" foi enviado
    if (isset($_POST['iusername']) == FALSE) {
        echo ("Erro de submissão");
        exit();
    } else {
        $username = trim($_POST['iusername']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['inome']) == FALSE) {
        echo ("Erro de submissão");
        exit();
    } else {
        $nome = trim($_POST['inome']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['inivel']) == FALSE) {
        echo ("Erro de submissão");
        exit();
    } else {
        $apelido = trim($_POST['inivel']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['iativo']) == FALSE) {
        echo ("Erro de submissão");
        exit();
    } else {
        $telefone = trim($_POST['iativo']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['iemail']) == FALSE) {
        echo ("Erro de submissão");
        exit();
    } else {
    $email = trim($_POST['iemail']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['ipass']) == FALSE) {
    echo ("Erro de submissão");
    exit();
    } else {
    $pass = trim($_POST['ipass']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['irpass']) == FALSE) {
    echo ("Erro de submissão");
    exit();
    } else {
    $repass = trim($_POST['irpass']);
    }

    // Função de validação do email (chamada mais abaixo no código)
    function isValidEmail($email){
    return @eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]                                {2,3})", $email);

    // Validar se o nº de caracteres do "username" está entre 4 e 12
    if (strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 12) {
    $erro = true;
    $msgerro .= "<p>erro: \"username\" deve conter entre 4 e 12 caracteres</p>";
    }
    // Validar se o nome tem entre 3 e 40 caracteres
    if (strlen($nome) < 3 || strlen($nome) > 40) {
    //echo (strlen($nome));
    $erro = true;
    $msgerro .= "<p>erro: \"nome\" deve conter entre 3 a 40 caracteres</p>";
    }

// Validação das passwords
$mudapass = false;
    if (strlen($password) == 0 && strlen($rpassword) == 0) {
    $mudapass = false;
} else {
    $mudapass = true;
}
    // 2.2. Validar o tamanho da password
    if (strlen($password) < 4 || strlen($password)> 16) {
    $erro = true;
    $msgerro .= "<p>erro: \"password\" deve conter entre 4 a 16 caracteres</p>";
    }
    }
    // 3. Validar se as duas passwords correspondem
    if ($password != $rpassword) {
    $erro = true;
    $msgerro .= "<p>\"passwords\" não correspondem</p>";
    }

    // validação de email
    // Chama a nova função "isValidEmail"
    if (isValidEmail($email) == false) {
    $erro = true;
    $msgerro .= "<p>email inválido</p>";
    } 
     // Final das validações (avisa caso algum erro seja detectado)
    if ($erro) {
    echo "<p>Formulário submetido com erros</p>";
    echo $msgerro;
    echo "<br>";
    // Desenha 2 botões "Corrigir" e "Listar"
    echo "<a class='ains' href='javascript:history.go(-1)' title='Volta à página         anterior'>Corrigir </a>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<a class='ains' href='lista.php'>Listar</a>";
    exit();
    }
    if($password != $rpassword){
echo "ERRO: PASSWORDS SAO DIFERENTES";
    }


    $sql= "UPDATE usuarios SET
        nome = '$nome';
        email = '$email';
        nivel = '$nivel';
        ativo = '$ativo';
        WHERE
        usuario = '$username'";

    if ($mudapass == TRUE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET nome = '$nome', 
    password = '$password', 
    email = '$email',
    nivel = '$nivel', 
    ativo = '$ativo', WHERE usuario = '$username'";
    }
    if ($mudapass == FALSE) {
    $sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET
    nome = '$nome',
    email = '$email',
    nivel = '$nivel',
    ativo = '$ativo'
    WHERE
    usuario = '$username'";
    }
    $connection->query($sql);
    // Lista users depois de actualizar
    header("location:lista.php");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a naming problem. Two of your variables don't seem to follow the same convention as the rest of them, and unless I'm missing some extra processing before the query, then you should change these two lines:

```
    $apelido = trim($_POST['inivel']);

    // ...several lines later
    $telefone = trim($_POST['iativo']);
```

to this:

```
    $nivel = trim($_POST['inivel']);

    // ...several lines later
    $ativo = trim($_POST['iativo']);
```

Comment: No problem!:D
Also, since the problem is solved, you can acknowledge it by accepting the answer

Comment: sorry didnt knew the system of accepting, done, sorry for taking so long!

Comment: Haha don't worry about it! Thanks for accepting, and goodluck with the coding! :D